# Using XSLT to create a well formatted nested table from unknown XML

Tags: php, xml, xslt, dom, xslt-1.0

**The task I was given:**
My boss wants me to create an XSLT that takes XML of an unknown structure, and put it into a nested table (tag names as table headers) without repeating table headers where possible. I was almost able to get what he wants (The table )

**The question:**
I have only worked with XSLT's for a few days now (have gone through a few tutorials and played with it a bit), So if anyone can point me in a good direction on where to find information that will help me with my problem, it would be greatly appreciated.

**Environment Data:** I am working with XSLT and PHP (DOM objects). My boss wants me to become the companies XSLT expert, so if it is possible through pure XSLT, it would be appreciated.

**Additional info:** At the request of the people responding, additional info (code) is below.The task is to turn something like the XML snippet below into the table below for displaying. Unfortunately, the code I had is in a state of flux at the moment, so I will not be posting it (if the question is still open when I get it stable again, I will post it).

**XML Snippet:**

```
<root>
    <request>
        <details>
            <columnname>name1</columnname>
            <operator></operator>
            <value>val</value>
            <seq>1</seq>
        </details>
    </request>
    <request>
        <details>
            <columnname>name2</columnname>
            <operator>OP</operator>
            <value>val</value>
            <seq>2</seq>
        </details>
    </request>
    <request>
        <details>
            <columnname>name3</columnname>
            <value>val</value>
            <seq>3</seq>
        </details>
    </request>
    <response>
        <details>
            <columnname>name4</columnname>
            <value>val</value>
            <seq>4</seq>
        </details>
    </response>
</root>
```

**Desired Output**

```
<table border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;width:100%">
    <tr>
        <th>root</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;width:100%">
                <tr>
                    <th>request</th>
                    <th>response</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;width:100%">
                            <tr>
                                <th>details</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <table border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;width:100%">
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>columnname</th>
                                            <th>operator</th>
                                            <th>value</th>
                                            <th>seq</th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>name1</td>
                                            <td></td>
                                            <td>val</td>
                                            <td>1</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>name2</td>
                                            <td>OP</td>
                                            <td>val</td>
                                            <td>2</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>name3</td>
                                            <td></td>
                                            <td>val</td>
                                            <td>3</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <table border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;width:100%">
                            <tr>
                                <th>details</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <table border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;width:100%">
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>columnname</th>
                                            <th>value</th>
                                            <th>seq</th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>name4</td>
                                            <td>val</td>
                                            <td>4</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Response to michael.hor257k:** It would look something like this.

```
<table border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;width:100%">
    <tr>
        <th>root</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;width:100%">
                <tr>
                    <th>parent</th>
                    <th>uncle</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;width:100%">
                            <tr>
                                <th>child</th>
                                <th>nephew</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <table border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;width:100%">
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>string</th>
                                            <th>number</th>
                                            <th>grandchild</th>
                                            <th>date</th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>A</td>
                                            <td></td>
                                            <td></td>
                                            <td></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>B</td>
                                            <td></td>
                                            <td></td>
                                            <td></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>C</td>
                                            <td>1</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <table border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;width:100%">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th>string</th>
                                                        <th>substring</th>
                                                        <th>number</th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>DD</td>
                                                        <td>EE</td>
                                                        <td>33</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                            <td></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td></td>
                                            <td>2</td>
                                            <td></td>
                                            <td></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>F</td>
                                            <td></td>
                                            <td></td>
                                            <td>2015-02-12</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <table border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;width:100%">
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>string</th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>G</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <table border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;width:100%">
                            <tr>
                                <th>niece</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <table border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;width:100%">
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>string</th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>H</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I am not sue what a "*nested table*" means. Please post an example or two of input and the expected output of each.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. This is an excellent resource to "help me with my problem", BUT we need to understand your problem as some specfic code that needs fixing. If you are "almost able to get what he want", then edit your question to include a. a small sample of input data, b. your expected output from that data, c. the code you are using, d. any details about the environment you are using (java, saxon parsers, etc, OR xsh, xmllint, xmlstarlet, etc e. current output and any error messages. Use the `{}` format tool at the top left of text edit box to highlight your code and data to fmt.

Comment: As currently phrased, your question is likely to be voted closed because you are "request(ing) a recommend for tool, library, tutorial etc" . Good luck.

Comment: michael.hor257k: Nesting tables is like nesting if statements (tables inside tables).

Comment: Thank you very much for the information shellter, I will attempt to remember your advice for any future posts.

Comment: The connection between input and output is not clear. Where in the input is `response` or `name4`? And why is `filters` omitted from the output?

Comment: Sorry about that, I meant to remove the filters to make the code shorter, and add a response tag. Since this is a lower priority than the other tasks I have, I rushed it a bit. The post has been updated.

Comment: This could easily prove to be **much** more difficult than it may seem. It's hard to tell for sure with your rather simple example. Could you provide the expected output for the XML tree I posted here: http://pastebin.com/5Xa2fYHN ?

Comment: @michael.hor257k: I put the code in the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments, this is not going to be simple. Basically, you want to remove any duplicate nodes that have the same *path* (where a path is calculated using only node names) and display the resulting hierarchy.

This requires making a pre-processing pass to assign all nodes their path. We also need to provide each node with its parent path - so that it can be called later by its new parent (which formerly could be its uncle or great-uncle or...).

In the second - and final - step we will be applying [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) to the result of the first pass, leaving only distinct nodes by path.

In this example I will be processing only elements, and the result will be presented as an unordered list.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="node-by-path" match="node" use="@path" />
<xsl:key name="node-by-parent-path" match="node" use="@parent-path" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- first-pass -->
    <xsl:variable name="first-pass">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="firstpass"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- output -->
    <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($first-pass)/node[@parent-path='']" />
    </ul>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="firstpass">
    <xsl:variable name="parent-path">
        <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::*">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('/', name())"/>
        </xsl:for-each>                 
    </xsl:variable> 
    <node name="{name()}" parent-path="{$parent-path}" path="{concat($parent-path, '/', name())}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="firstpass"/>
    </node>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node">
    <li>
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
        <xsl:variable name="next" select="key('node-by-parent-path', @path)" />
        <xsl:if test="$next">
            <ul>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$next[count(. | key('node-by-path', @path)[1]) = 1]"/>
            </ul>
        </xsl:if>
    </li>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Test input XML**

```
<root>
   <parent>
      <child>
         <string>A</string>
         <string>B</string>
      </child>
      <child>
         <string>C</string>
         <number>1</number>
         <number>2</number>
         <grandchild>
            <string>DD</string>
            <substring>EE</substring>
            <number>33</number>
         </grandchild>
      </child>
   </parent>
   <parent>
      <child>
         <string>F</string>
         <date>2015-02-12</date>
      </child>
      <nephew>
         <string>G</string>
      </nephew>
   </parent>
   <uncle>
      <niece>
         <string>H</string>
      </niece>
   </uncle>
</root>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ul>
   <li>root<ul>
         <li>parent<ul>
               <li>child<ul>
                     <li>string</li>
                     <li>number</li>
                     <li>grandchild<ul>
                           <li>string</li>
                           <li>substring</li>
                           <li>number</li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                     <li>date</li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
               <li>nephew<ul>
                     <li>string</li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li>uncle<ul>
               <li>niece<ul>
                     <li>string</li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

**Rendered**

[image]